# Must the number of people...

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs

> Must the number of people at the party who do not know an odd number of people be even? Describe a graph model and then answers the question.

I'm confused because I do not understand the question. For example if we take people to be a vertex, then if there is an edge between them it means that people know each other, 
and the formula is $$\sum d(v) = 2*e$$ $\Rightarrow$ the sum of degrees of all vertices should be even so it means that there should be an even number of vertices. But why in the question is "people who do not know an odd number of other people be even"..?

Answer (score 2):

The number of people a person knows is the degree of a vertex. As you've noted, the sum of the degrees must be even. Thus the number of vertices of odd degree must be even. However, the question is asking about vertices of even degree, and there are no restrictions in this sense on these; all of the vertices in a cycle graph have even degree, and cycles can be of any length greater than $2$.

Comment: So,the answer is no? There is no restriction for people who don't know an odd number of people?

Comment: @Margarita the answer is no, but justification is required to make such a bold statement. Something like my example.

Comment: I was confused by the problem statement. I couldn't figure out if "I do not know an odd number of people" means "the number of people I know is not an odd number" or "the number of people I do not know is an odd number". From your answer, it appears that the first interpretation is correct. **How did you know that?**

Comment: @bof are you a native speaker of English? If not it's understandable, I can imagine it being different in other languages. "Do not" is negating "know an odd number of people," and "do not know" is not a verb phrase.

Comment: If the problem was written by a non-native speaker (note the erroneous "answers" on the second line) then the rules of English grammar may not be a sure guide to the meaning. In any case the wording seems very strange. I can't imagine why anyone would say "who do not know an even number of people" instead of "who know an odd number of people."

Comment: @bof getting the alternative meaning requires rearranging the word order. "The number of people I do not know is odd" can only be given the alternative meaning, which is not the same as "I do not know an odd number of people." It's true that it's a strange way to word it, and the only reason it's unambiguous is because there are only two options (even and odd).

Answer (score 0):

Construct a graph whose vertices are the people, and two vertices are adjacent if the two people know each other.  The number of people who do not know an odd number of people is equal to the number of people who know an even number of people (because there are only two possibilities for the degree of a vertex - even or odd).  So you are considering the number of vertices of even degree.  This value is not restricted in any way.  If the graph is an odd cycle, then the number of vertices of even degree is odd.  So the answer to your question is a "no".

Comment: Thank you i understand this, but for me question seems confusing " people who do not know odd number of people should be odd" why not just" should people who know even number of people be even"?...strange

Comment: @Margarita it's possible it was phrased this way to slip up most students and ensure only the "best" students get the right answer. Unfortunately it doesn't account for a language barrier.

Comment: @Margarita Well, you are right the question is easier to understand if the double-negative was avoided. I agree with you it is strange to ask this question because we are not really testing mathematical abilities by introducing double-negatives.